# Firefox image sprites displays alt text

Tags: css, firefox

In a web application I am using images sprites that have alt text.  But in Firefox only the actual alt-text overlays the image on screen.

```
<img width="36" height="36" class="step1Current" title="Step 1" alt="Quote step one image">
```

Its class is:

```
.step1Current{
    background: url(../images/progress-sprites.png) no-repeat;  
    background-position: 0px 0px ;
    width: 36px;
    height: 36px;   
}
```

So the image is overlayed with the text 'Quote step one image'.

Comment: don't used to background properties on img tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use a background on an `img` tag.

If you don't specify a `src=""` god knows what will happen, the `alt` should show up.

Inline sprites: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites-with-inline-images/

Live Demo: http://css-tricks.com/examples/CSSClip/

The key is the `clip` property, which works all the way down to IE6.